# C strings and pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct wordlist {
    char *value;
    struct wordlist *next;
};
int compare (struct wordlist *one , struct wordlist *two) {
    return strcmp(one->value, two->value);
}
void add(struct wordlist *pp, char *value) {
    struct wordlist *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->value = value;
    for ( ; pp != NULL; pp = pp->next) {
        if (compare(pp, new) > 0 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    new->next = pp;
    pp = new;
}
void display(struct wordlist *ptr) {
    for (; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr->value);
    }
}
```

breaking it in the middle in order to submit. sorry

```
int main(void) {
    struct wordlist *root = NULL;
    add(root, "item1");
    add(root, "item2");
    add(root, "item4");
    add(root, "item3");
    display(root);
    return 0;
}
```

It should print out

> item1 item2 item3 item4

but its not printing any thing and I don't understand why.

Comment: Yeah, me too,,,,,why cannot `change (5);` does not change `5`.. :D

Comment: lol, I understand the code but I cant see any reason it wont work

Comment: Which line? @TonyTannous

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/bVuSsq)

Comment: thats just what i needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method doesn't change root and also work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct wordlist {
    char *value;
    struct wordlist *next;
};

int compare (struct wordlist *one , struct wordlist *two) {
    return strcmp(one->value, two->value);
}

void add(struct wordlist *pp, char *value) {
    struct wordlist *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->value = value;

    for ( ; pp->next != NULL; pp = pp->next) {
        if (compare(pp->next, new) > 0 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    new->next = pp->next;
    pp->next = new;

}
void display(struct wordlist *ptr) {
    while ( ptr->next != NULL ) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("%s\n", ptr->value);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct wordlist root;

    root.next = NULL;
    add(&root, "item1");
    add(&root, "item2");
    add(&root, "item4");
    add(&root, "item3");
    display(&root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It dose but i don't wanna change the root all the time. thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you need to pass a pointer to a pointer?

```
void add(struct wordlist **pp, char *value) {
struct wordlist *new;
new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
new->value = value;
for ( ; (*pp) != NULL; (*pp) = (*pp)->next) {
    if (compare((*pp), new) > 0 ) {
        break;
    }
}
new->next = (*pp);
(*pp) = new;
}
```

Comment: You should use other variable in for-loop

Comment: Also The list before the insertion position is lost.

Comment: *All* `pp`s from the OP should become `(*pp)`s in your proposal.

Comment: This `*pp->next` needs be `(*pp)->next`!

Comment: `(*pp) = (*pp)->next)` This is fatally bad.